# How to send BytesIO image through Telegram bot when user chooses command?

Tags: python, python-telegram-bot, bytesio

I am trying to make a telegram bot(python-telegram-bot) that sends an image which I web scraped, combined and converted into bytes from another script. Problem now is I am not sure how to call the image object and send it through the Telegram script.

```
def weather_command(update,context):
    chat_id = update.message.chat_id
    document = NEAData.weatherimage()
    context.bot.send_document(chat_id,document)
```

Is there a simpler or better way to do this?

Comment: What does the telegram documentation say?

Comment: idk how to read it. I'm using telegram.ext

Comment: do you get error message or what? Code seems OK. What is `NEAData` ?

Answer (score 1):

Was able to solve it myself. Instead of having the image already in a byte object, I combined the images in PNG first in NEAData(the script which runs the web scraping and combining of images).Then I called the image in the Telegram script(main script) then converted it into bytes to send through the bot.

```
def weather_command(update,context):
    with BytesIO() as image:
        NEAData.image.save(image, "png")
        image.seek(0)
        update.message.reply_photo(image)
```